# How can I print just specific elements of a Java 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the code I'm messing with, pretty basic. I was looking for a way to print only specific elements of the array. For example, if I wanted to print only the element at index 1 of `array[i]`, as well as the element at index 1 of `array[j]` when its value is 1. See below for the output I'm looking for.

Expected output :

```
1 3 5
  4
7 8 9
```

Code:

```java
public class multiDimensional {

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int arr[][] = {{1,3,5}, {2,4,6}, {7,8,9}};

        for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){
                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
                //System.out.println();
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }

}
```

Actual output :

```
1 3 5
2 4 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: You will want to check out the if statement and how to use it. Introductory control statement tutorials can help with this.

Comment: I'm not sure how your 'for example' matches your example output. I have answered according to your example output.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to map your description to your expectations. The actual output is expected based on you code as you simply print all the elements.

Comment: `if (i == 1) { if (j == 1) { System.out.print(arr[i][j]); } else { System.out.print(" "); } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce your expected output by using an `if` statement to decide when to write a value:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int arr[][] = {{1,3,5}, {2,4,6}, {7,8,9}};

    for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < 3; j++){

            if (i == 0             // in the first row
                || i == 2      // in the last row
                || j == 1) {   // in the middle column of the middle row

                System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");

            } else {

                System.out.print("  ");    // this is here to keep the spacing right

            }
            //System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**Note:** There are many other ways of coding this, however the approach I am showing is merely to demonstrate how the `if` statement works.

Comment: @95C3ntS If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left.